# File created in ASP app disappears when another file is created - how can I get both files?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP web app with a page that has two buttons, each of which creates an Excel file that can be opened or saved. However, it takes so long to generate a file that a user can click on the button for one file, and then, before the file is generated, click on the button for the other file. When this happens, the code to generate the first file runs successfully, but the first file never appears - only the second one.

How do I get the app to display both of the requested reports?

The obvious answer is probably something like, "When you click on one of the buttons, disable the two buttons until the file is generated" - but when a button is pressed, the page doesn't refresh while the first file is being generated.

Comment: you can have each form target a hidden iframe with separate page for each.  (two separate iframes, and two separate pages) This should allow for async generation of the files.  Something like: <form method="post" action="Export" target="export_file1_iframe">

Comment: come to think of it, you wouldn't need separate pages, just separate iframes.  Forms should pass info to generate the separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could start another separate thread/process for this code to run, and then the page round trip would be short and fast.

I suppose the other way?

Add some JavaScript code to "hide" the button - and after the page is done, then it will re-fresh and the button will re-enable.

So, add this to the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="130px" 
            OnClientClick="bt1Disable();return True;"/>
    <script>
       function bt1Disable() {
          document.getElementById('<%= Button1.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";

       }
    </script>
```

There are a good number of examples (even on SO) that suggest to disable the button. But if you disable the button - then the server side code does NOT run. So, it simple (and best) to just hide the button as per above. When the page is finished the round trip, then the button will re-display back to its original setting.

I would in fact suggest that you put code in to hide BOTH buttons this way. That way, while the user waits - they can't click on either button.

And if you want to get cute? Then hide/show a small "gif" spinner - it will thus "spin" while they wait and again the page round trip will hide that spinner (gif) by default.